# How backup databases when mysql is stopped

Tags: mysql

I am on a VPS of 40Go and having 20go of free space with an additionnal disk storage of 50Go. On my additionnal disk is running all my databases but a problem appears: the additionnal disk is full due to a huge ibdata file (48Go).
Due to a full disk, i'm not able to /etc/init.d/mysql start and so, I can't dump.
What can I do to save my databases ?
My tools: 
Debian shell with Root access - PuTTY - WinSCP

Comment: MySQL usually saves the databases in a folder like `mysql\data\dbname`, you can just copy the whole directory I think.

Comment: I tried this, but saddly, it doesn't work. I think those folders need ibdata1 datas to work properly. I tried too to launch a VM and grab everything (with WinSCP) to be able to mysqldump but got a failed when launching mysql on the VM